# How to publish a post with an attachment on Facebook At Work using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Javascript SDK with **Facebook at Work** Graph API and my goal is to be able to publish a post to a user's wall, preferably with an attachment, or maybe create an event.

The documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-at-work/graph-api/reference - appears to be broken: the link for /events is 404 and the link for /feed redirects to the section about reading existing posts, not publishing new ones.

So how do you publish a post to a user's wall in Facebook at work? Or is this part of Graph API mostly read-only, except trivial things like posting likes?

Comment: From the very beginning of the page you linked to: _“This is a full list of **readable** Graph API root nodes for Facebook at Work.”_

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure how to interpret it. Does it mean there's a list of publishable nodes somewhere? Maybe publishable non-root nodes? Or is it a definite 'no'? @CBroe

Comment: It says it uses a subset of the Graph API. So if publishing is possible, I’d expect it to work the same way, as publishing does in Graph API. So what have you tried/tested in that regard?

Comment: By subset it means "Not all of the Graph API endpoints are applicable to Facebook at Work.". So I would like to know whether you or anyone else have any experience with publishing a post using the API. There is no way I can test it because my Facebook At Work account is still pending review. Using a standard account for that purpose would make no sense, I know how to publish a post on normal Facebook.

Comment: _“There is no way I can test it because my Facebook At Work account is still pending review”_ – well wait until that’s done then.

Comment: That helped, thanks @CBroe